# Close open sockets from crashed program

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, sockets

I am opening thousand of sockets and sometimes the program crashes leaving me with a lot less available sockets. Is there a way to clean those hanging sockets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sockets are finally closed by the Unix kernel; a crashed program is no different from a normal program exit w/o a `close()/shutdown()` call.

Your problem may have to do with the TIME_WAIT state of the TCP/IP state machine and should be solved with the SO_REUSEADDR option. One way to confirm this is wait for about 5 minutes before starting again after a crash. If you find sufficient sockets are now available you should study the TIME_WAIT logic and work around it. If the wait trick does not solve your problem there might be a different issue in your program which needs to be identified then.

Here is a good read on the subject,
[TIME_WAIT and its design implications for protocols and scalable client server systems](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2011/01/time-wait-and-its-design-implications-for-protocols-and-scalable-servers.html)

Two quick extracts from there for reference,

> TIME_WAIT is often also known as the 2MSL wait state. This is because
>   the socket that transitions to TIME_WAIT stays there for a period that
>   is 2 x Maximum Segment Lifetime in duration. The MSL is the maximum
>   amount of time that any segment, for all intents and purposes a
>   datagram that forms part of the TCP protocol, can remain valid on the
>   network before being discarded. This time limit is ultimately bounded
>   by the TTL field in the IP datagram that is used to transmit the TCP
>   segment. Different implementations select different values for MSL and
>   common values are 30 seconds, 1 minute or 2 minutes. RFC 793 specifies
>   MSL as 2 minutes and Windows systems default to this value but can be
>   tuned using the TcpTimedWaitDelay registry setting.

(PS: hence the `4+1` minute wait for my test suggested above)

> Changing the 2MSL delay is usually a machine wide configuration
>   change. You can instead attempt to work around TIME_WAIT at the socket
>   level with the SO_REUSEADDR socket option. This allows a socket to be
>   created whilst an existing socket with the same address and port
>   already exists. The new socket essentially hijacks the old socket. You
>   can use SO_REUSEADDR to allow sockets to be created whilst a socket
>   with the same port is already in TIME_WAIT but this can also cause
>   problems such as denial of service attacks or data theft.

The article describes one more way. But that comes with other caveats.

> There's another way to terminate a TCP connection and that's by
>   aborting the connection and sending an RST rather than a FIN. This is
>   usually achieved by setting the SO_LINGER socket option to 0. This
>   causes pending data to be discarded and the connection to be aborted
>   with an RST rather than for the pending data to be transmitted and the
>   connection closed cleanly with a FIN. It's important to realise that
>   when a connection is aborted any data that might be in flow between
>   the peers is discarded and the RST is delivered straight away; usually
>   as an error which represents the fact that the "connection has been
>   reset by the peer". The remote peer knows that the connection was
>   aborted and neither peer enters TIME_WAIT.

Before using these schemes it is a good idea to understand the TCP machine behavior so you do not inadvertently introduce other situations which will need debug later. So at least read that article completely `:-)`